# terraform user-data not working though rendered

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, user-data

I am creating an ec2 machine and when it is up, I want docker installed in it and add itself to rancher server

the terraform script for the same is

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "ap-south-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "rancherHost" {
    tags {
        name = "tf-rancher-host-rmf44"
    }

    ami                    = "ami-0189d76e"
    instance_type          = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.port500and4500.id}"]
    user_data              = "${data.template_file.user-data.rendered}"
}

data template_file "user-data"
{
    template = "${file("script.sh")}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "port500and4500" {
    ingress {
        from_port   = 500
        protocol    = "udp"
        to_port     = 500
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    ingress {
        from_port   = 4500
        protocol    = "udp"
        to_port     = 4500
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress {
        from_port = 443
        protocol = "tcp"
        to_port = 443
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress {
        from_port = 80
        protocol = "tcp"
        to_port = 80
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}
output "instanceDetail" {
    value = "${aws_instance.rancherHost.public_ip}"
}
```

And the script I have written is in the same directory,  the contents are :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "fail fast learn fast"
echo "this is second line"
apt-get update -y || echo $?
apt-get install -y docker
apt-get install -y docker.io
echo "echo failing now maybe"
service docker start
```

When I ran this, the machine is created also the user-data is visible, also I checked the logs, only first two echos were present and nothing else. am I doing something wrong here, manual creation using same user data worked and the host was added to rancher server.
os is ubuntu 16.04

Comment: SSH onto the machine and run `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data | base`. This allows you to execute the script and perhaps get better feedback as to why the script is having issues.

Comment: I ran your script in a Ubuntu and in worked fine for me isolated in a Ubuntu docker container. Also, check the `Get System Log` on your EC2 instance. Might give you more insight.

Comment: One thing we've seen with Packer builds is that Ubuntu is doing something with `apt` repos during boot that locks them and causes `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` commands to fail if you run them too early. Try adding a `sleep 30` before your first `apt-get update` and see if that helps. Also, see the following link for how to get User Data scripts to log to file so you can debug what happened: https://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output/

Comment: @Nate yes , I have checked the system log, only the first two echos got printed and nothing else even the third or condition was not printed